# Finding good Corpus for Finding sentences containing pair of words

Tags: python, nlp, wikipedia, corpus

I want to find many sentences containing pair of words in a sentence database that is representative of a real world. For example - I would want many sentences that contain both words "person" and "walking". I have two questions:

Is there some large corpus available which I can directly invoke for this purpose?

If I have some such large corpora, id there online application available that does it for me? Or if I code it myself, how to go about it in Python?

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia is a pretty good collection of sentences containing pair of words and the code to get them into vectors is here: https://github.com/idio/wiki2vec